Punic name of Pantelleria island
The ancient name of Pantelleria island (Sicilia, Italy) is usually written in latin characters as YRNM.
I relied on a table to convert these characters in punic characters and (considering punics wrote from right to left) I obtained the name ‎‎.
However I found a few pictures of coins with a different set of characters on them.
In the picture the first character looks different and there seem to be an additional sign between the first and second character. Unfortunately coins are a bit worn out and I'm not able to discern precisely the characters on them.
What is the reason for these differences and what is the proper way to write Pantelleria punic name in unicode characters?

The coin says  ʾYRNM, which is an alternative name. Note that your transcription of YRNM is incorrect:  is K.

Thank you for your answer. Could you please provide any reference?

The Wikipedia article that coin image is from mentions the variant.

ʾYRNM is also probably to be expected on etymological grounds, ʾY being a common Semitic word meaning "island" (see Hebrew אי ʾî "island"), the name then presumably meaning "the Island of the RNs"
